# Django 1.9 Can't leave formfield blank issue

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-1.9

I modified my forms to show a new label for the fields in my model. Now I can't have a user leave the form field blank. I've tried to add blank=True and null=True, but without luck. How can I allow fields to be blank?

My Model:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    # Page 1
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=100, blank=True, unique=True)

    # Page 2 Address
    line1 = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    line2 = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    line3 = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=2, blank=True, null=True)
    zip_code = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

forms.py:

```
class UserProfileForm3(forms.ModelForm):
    line1 = forms.CharField(label="Address")
    line2 = forms.CharField(label="")
    line3 = forms.CharField(label="")
    city = forms.CharField(label="City / Town")
    state = forms.CharField(label="State / Province / Region")
    zip_code = forms.IntegerField(label="Zip / Postal Code")

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(UserProfileForm3, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['line1'].widget.attrs = {
            'class': 'form-control',
            'placeholder': 'Address Line 1'
        }
        self.fields['line2'].widget.attrs = {
            'class': 'form-control',
            'placeholder': 'Address Line 2'
        }
        self.fields['line3'].widget.attrs= {
            'class': 'form-control',
            'placeholder': 'Address Line 3'
        }
        self.fields['city'].widget.attrs = {
            'class': 'form-control',
            'placeholder': 'City'
        }
        self.fields['state'].widget.attrs = {
            'id': 'state_id',
            'class': 'form-control',
            'placeholder': 'State'
        }
        self.fields['zip_code'].widget.attrs = {
            'id': 'zip_code_id',
            'class': 'form-control',
            'placeholder': 'Zip'
        }
        self.fields['country'].widget.attrs = {
            'class': 'form-control',
            'placeholder': 'US',
            'value': 'US'
        }

    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ('line1', 'line2', 'line3', 'city', 'state', 'zip_code','country')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add this in forms.py:

```
self.fields['line1'].required = false
```

You will have to do this for every field.

Comment: Both yours and Daniel's worked. However, with yours I was able to also write a clean_data function to write my own Validation Error. The other method, wouldn't let me do this as simply.

Answer (score 2):

You overrode the fields, so they won't preserve any of the attributes; you need to set them explicitly.

```
line1 = forms.CharField(label="Address", required=False)
```

Note also that your model field definitions shouldn't have `null=True` for CharFields, this is bad practice.

Comment: Thank you Daniel, for sharing that null=True is bad practice. I'll check into proper practice for writing CharFields and correct my models. I didn't realize that this was not something to do! To be honest, I'm so new to Django that even reading the docs gets me confused.

Comment: See [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#null): "Avoid using null on string-based fields such as CharField and TextField because empty string values will always be stored as empty strings, not as NULL. If a string-based field has null=True, that means it has two possible values for “no data”: NULL, and the empty string. In most cases, it’s redundant to have two possible values for “no data;” the Django convention is to use the empty string, not NULL."